# The difference between は and を?

Tags: meaning, particle-は

Hello everyone as the title states I am having difficulty understanding when to use the correct particle.

As an example

> 肉は食べません (I do not eat meat)

and

> やさいを食べます (I eat vegetables)

Is it acceptable to use both wa or o in both these sentences? Wouldn't the first sentence be more correct if I were to say 私は肉を食べません. The reason I chose these two specific sentences is because I saw them in a book. I can not understand why in one sentence they used は while in the other they used を even though they have the same basic structure.

Thank you for any help you may provide!

Comment: Having stated は is always to indicate the subject/theme/topic of the sentence, I think I should say it differs from では or とは. ^^;

Comment: ^ `always` <-- Naw. The は's in these examples do NOT indicate subject/theme/topic: 「普段**は**いい子なのに・・・」「10万円**は**するぞ！」「私は、電気**は**嫌いです。(by バーサ in 魔女宅. There can't be two topics in one clause)」

Comment: I don't see a point of marking this as a duplicate. How a learner can tell the other thread talking about ではない is the one to read when having trouble knowing why it's は instead of を? I myself need a lot of time to read the whole thing and determine if it's really related or not.

Comment: I don't think the word indicated by ではありません or とは思いません can be rewritten as an object of the verb. Isn't the point actually different from the other thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [野菜]{やさい}**を**食べます。 vs 野菜**は**食べます。

*Grammatically speaking*, both are correct. They're different in meaning and usage.

を is the object marker. 野菜を食べます is usually an unmarked statement to say "I eat/someone eats vegetables". The は can be, roughly speaking, the topic particle (主題の「は」) or the contrastive particle (対比の「は」). For example, you can use them this way:

> 「普段、朝食に何を食べますか？」--「野菜**を**食べます。」(not は)
>   "What do you usually have for breakfast?" -- "I have vegetables."
>   「鈴虫は何を食べますか？」--「ナスやキュウリなどの野菜**を**食べます。」(not は)
>   "What do bell crickets eat?" -- "They eat vegetables such as aubergine and cucumber."

Here, the を marks new information (新情報).

> 「普段、野菜は食べますか？」--「はい、野菜**は**たくさん食べます。」(not を)
>   "Do you eat vegetables regularly?" -- "Yes, (*lit.* As for vegetables, I eat a lot. →) I eat a lot of vegetables."

The は is the so-called "topical/thematic は". Here, it marks old/known information (旧情報/既知情報).

は can also be used this way:

> 「野菜**は**食べます。でも肉**は**食べません。」
>   "I eat vegetables. But I don't eat meat."
>   「鈴虫は*、肉**は**食べませんが、野菜**は**食べます。」
>   "Bell crickets don't eat meat, but they eat vegetables."
>   <sub>*The は in 鈴虫は is a topic marker; there can be only one topical は in a clause. If you see two は's in one clause, at least one of them should be contrastive.</sub>

The は here is the so-called "contrastive は". (You could refer to this thread for more about the contrastive は: [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/9831))

---

> 肉**は**食べません。 vs 肉**を**食べません。

Again, they're both *grammatically* correct, and different in meaning 
and usage.

The は can be topical/thematic:

> 「お肉はよく召し上がりますか？」--「いいえ、肉**は**まったく食べません。」(not を)
>   "Do you eat meat often?" -- "No, I don't eat meat at all."

The contrastive は is also used to mark or highlight the negated element in a sentence:

> 普段、朝食に肉**は**食べません。
>   I usually don't have meat for breakfast (can imply: but I have something else).
>   普段、朝食に**は**肉を食べません。
>   I usually don't have meat for breakfast (can imply: but I do for dinner).
>   普段**は**、朝食に肉を食べません。
>   I usually don't have meat for breakfast (can imply: but I do today).

Here, the は shows the scope of negation: 肉を* is negated in the first sentence, and 朝食に is negated in the second, and so on.
<sub>* When 「XXを」 or 「XXが」 is marked with a は, the は replaces the が or を,
 as in 「XXは」 rather than 「XXをは」「XXがは」.</sub>
There usually is some negated element in a negative sentence, and therefore you'll more frequently see a は in a negative sentence.

As for the example using an を, you'd use it in a context like this:

> 「子どもの好き嫌いが激しくて…。」--「何を食べてくれないんですか？」--「野菜**を**ぜんぜん食べないんです。」(not は)
>   "My child is so picky about food..." -- "What does s/he not eat?" -- "S/he doesn't eat vegetables at all."
>   <sub>You'd reply with 「～を」「～が」「～に」「～と」「～から」 etc., not 「～は」「～には」「～とは」「～からは」 etc. to questions 「何を」「何が」「どこに」「誰と」 etc., as in: 「何がないんですか？」「消しゴム**が**ないんです。」(not は) / 「誰と連絡がつかないんですか？」「山田さん**と**連絡がつかないんです。」(not とは）</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> > 肉は食べません ( I do not eat meat) and やさいを食べます (I eat vegetables)
>
> Is it acceptable to use both wa or o in both these sentences?
> Wouldnt the first sentence be more correct if i were to say 私は肉を食べません.
> I can not understand why in one sentence they used は while in the other they used を even though the they have the same basic structure.

**In Japanese, the *subject* is *not necessarily* the action maker.** The verb forms are made in such a way that we can, most of the time, tell the action maker without it being stated. **は** for us is always to indicate the subject. I'd say therefore it's more truly a subject than the English subject. The Japanese subject always means the ***theme/topic*** of the sentence, as the name 'subject' suggests.

私は肉を食べません is the word-to-word translation from English, *I don't eat meat.* But this is not very natural in Japanese, although there's no problem to say the action maker and say 私**は**肉**は**食べませんが、魚（さかな）**は**食べます。

---

[Replying to the OP's request below]
I find お茶は飲みません is the natural one to stand alone.

お茶を飲みません ... I find this expression does need the action maker and say, for example, この人はお茶を飲みません, and この人 suggests it's someone close to the speaker such as a family or friend. It sounds nicer than この人はお茶は飲みません.

Thinking like this makes me also think that **私は肉を食べません** and **私はお茶を飲みません** can be a well constructed sentence. So nice that we rarely hear it, but indeed these sound nicer than 私は肉は食べません or 私はお茶は飲みません, which tend to sound like refusing an offer or something because of the nature of は to be used for **comparison**.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! To help me better understand may you please tell me what the difference is between these two sentences: お茶は飲みません and お茶を飲みません

Comment: I've replied to your comment in the above 'answer' section. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain(: I believe I have a much better understanding of its usage! Thank you

Comment: @karlalou Are you sure 魚は食べます is correct? My understanding was always that は when used in place of を is not functioning as a topic marker, but as a contrast marker, and to that end can only be used in a negative sentence. Also, I'm not so sure 私は肉を食べません is unnatural in general either... (although depending on the context, I guess it could be unnatural if emphasizing the contrast is important).

Comment: @Ataraxia I don't surprise that you've learned something adjusted to non-natives. But when は alone as particle, contrasting or not it's always the subject/theme to native speakers though it's just not necessarily the action maker, but it can be the object of the verb. 魚は食べます alone can be taken as saying 'fish eat,' however, when making a comparison, we say 肉は食べませんが、魚は食べます, as I stated above, or it can be 肉は食べますが、魚は食べません.  We do have the freedom to say these. 私は肉を食べません is not wrong, but I guess it sounds rigid to us because we are more used to say it with は. I am a native speaker. :)

Comment: You know what? I definitely feel 私は肉は食べません is natural but not 私は肉を食べません. For the latter, I definitely prefer 私は肉は食べません. I think it's because when we say we don't eat something we are like making a comparison because everyone must eat something else. We don't mean to make comparison when we say it but in some reason it has become natural to us to say it with は when we say we don't eat something.

Comment: I find emphasis can be made with any particle. は is good at comparison. が is good at exclusion, as is explained in (4) on this page: http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=916&TAB=2

Comment: [correction] The two comments earlier, the first "私は肉は食べません" should have been "私は肉を食べます."