# What does 通して聞く mean when they are used together?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を

long-time lurker, am hoping that I can get some help on something

I came upon a tweet which has this particular sentence "みなさんのパフォーマンスは通して聞くことでより魅力的..."

I am perplexed by how 通して聞く are used together. I understand how ~通して works and I have seen how it pairs with other verbs such as 見る so 通して見る, in this context of "ウィンドウを通して見ることができる" means looking through the window but I am not sure what does 通して means when it is paired with 聞く. I googled and I saw clauses such as "アルバムを通して聞く" which probably means listening throughout the album? Can I presume that in the context of the tweet, it means the same thing? Listening throughout the performance?

On an unrelated note, may I also ask whether は can be used with 通して? I normally see 通して used with を so I was a bit caught off.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this usage corresponds to the following definition of 通す/徹す from 大辞林:

> (とおして…する」の形で）始めから終わりまで休みなしにある動作をする。「全曲を—して聞く」「昼も夜も—して働く」

So ~を通して聞く would basically be "listen to 〜 straight through, from beginning to end."

Comment: I guess a non-literal translation might be "The more I hear, the more intrigued I am by everyone's performance".

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I will like to ask a follow-up question, I understand that とおして…する is normally paired with を like  ~を通して but in the earlier tweet, は is used instead which threw me off a little, can we use は with 通して or this is just a one-off quirk?

Comment: @Arcoirs, on the を vs. は, part of your question, maybe this will be helpful: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/49081/the-difference-between-は-and-を/49127#49127  And if after reading that it's still unclear, maybe it would be better to post a new question on this topic.

Comment: @Nanigashi I understand the difference between  を vs. は as particles but I am unsure of は  being used in the context ~を通して since I thought that を is necessary with ~を通して. I will post it as a separate question, thanks for your help (alongside with Earthliŋ♦)