# Can the を in ～を通して be replaced with は?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を

I asked an earlier question [What does 通して聞く mean when they are used together?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68563/what-does-%E9%80%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8F-mean-when-they-are-used-together/68564?noredirect=1#comment115753_68564) where I was confused by how a sentence used 通して but with a は instead of a を. Can someone help to shed some light on whether this is allowed, and if so.. under what instances can we use は instead?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object of a verb is usually marked with を, but when that object is the topic of the sentence, を will be replaced with は. This is a basic grammatical rule, and it has nothing to do with the usage of 通して itself. See: [What is a topic prominent language?](https://eastasiastudent.net/study/topic-prominent/)

In your example, みなさんのパフォーマンス is the topic of the sentence, so it's marked with は even though it's the object of 聞く.

Related:

- [What is the subject of this sentence? Is it the book (mentioned) or the author (who is not mentioned)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17571/5010)
- [The meaning and nuance behind the phrase "話は通してある"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48051/5010)
- ["は + verb" instead of "を + verb"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17817/5010)
- [Particle は replacing を - where does the stress lie?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010)

**EDIT**: Note that the object of みなさんのパフォーマンス is 聞く, not 通す. 通して is the te-form of 通す, and here it's working like an adverb that describes how the main action (聞く) is done. Compare: 音楽を座って聞く ("to listen to the music while sitting"), リンゴを急いで食べる ("to eat an apple in a hurry").

Comment: a follow-up question (sorry for pestering), as a foreign learner, I have learnt how certain phrases normally come with specific particles such as を+通して in this situation but I have recently come by to see that this is not always true, so it will make more sense to look at the clauses/sentence before determining whether we need to change the particles

Comment: ん？　今気づいたんですけど、"Edit" の冒頭の `the object of みなさんのパフォーマンス is 聞く, not 通す.` は、「みなさんのパフォーマンス is the object of 聞く, not 通す」じゃないでしょうか？